# How do I open another activity and change the URL of the web view located in that activity

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

How do I open another activity and change the URL of the web view located in that activity ? My current code keeps crashing. I can get it to work if i put a webview in main. The issue seems to be because its in another activity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val webView: WebView? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this, title(), date(), cat(),picture(),url())
    getTopStories()
    val mbtnTopStories = findViewById(R.id.btnTopStories) as Button
    val mbtnMostPopular = findViewById(R.id.btnMostPopular) as Button
    val mbtnArts = findViewById(R.id.btnArts) as Button

    mbtnTopStories.setOnClickListener {
        itemAdapter.deleteItems()
        getTopStories()
    }

    mbtnMostPopular.setOnClickListener {
        itemAdapter.deleteItems()
        getMostPopular()
    }

    mbtnArts.setOnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this, com.example.newsapp.WebView::class.java)
        this.startActivity(intent)
        val myWebView = WebView()
        WebView().webViewArticle.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webViewArticle)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
```

This is my error log

```
2021-07-17 19:20:46.243 4231-4231/com.example.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 4231
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:655)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:842)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:809)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:633)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
    at com.example.newsapp.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:84)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Why do you add webview in setOnClickListener ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your code you have one activity "WebView" which contains a web view and you need to load url inside this webview.

Then you should send this url from "MainActivity" to "WebView Activity" and all setting related to webview should be added on "WebviewActivity"

```
 mbtnArts.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, com.example.newsapp.WebView::class.java)
        this.startActivity(intent)
       
    }
```

And on WebViewAcivty

```
 WebView().webViewArticle.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webViewArticle)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```